# Difference between Cantor's diagonal argument and Cantor's theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anybody please help me if using [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) is sufficient to prove [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), which states that the powerset of a ([countable infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)) set $A$ is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) ?

Comment: You can use cantor's diagonal argument when proving cantor's theorem, because you will need to show that the power set of a countably infinite set is not countable. But they are distinct ideas.

Comment: You can see also [Cantor's first uncountability proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article#First_theorem).